# The probable casuse of flink source consumption speed bottleneck?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

A flink job with kafkaSource.The topic's total lag of kafka message will be millions after it runs a few days, then I restart the job, the millions of messages will be consumed in a few minutes, and it can run smoothy again for a few days:

[image]

Couldn't find answer by searching in google.

Comment: The url is the flink web ui.